# Racket vs Scheme macros

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

Do racket macros have more advanced functionality than those found in Scheme or Common Lisp?  I suspect so, especially regarding modules, namespaces and scoping, etc, but I'd appreciate a simple rundown of what Racket macros can do, if anything, that other lisps can not.

Additionally, Scheme/CL also expose the reader layer to the developer, and using this, is it not possible in those lisps to create entirely new languages (not just s-expr macros), such as Scribble, the way you can in Racket?

In other words, is Racket simply a philosophy/convention around "language oriented programming" with convenient syntactic wrappers to this end, or does it more fundamentally extend Scheme to do things technically impossible in that language?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two key features that make "language-oriented programming" work in Racket are:

- the module system allows the specification of a base language
- context-sensitive macros

The first bullet is basically what `#lang` does. Having the module system be in charge of setting up the reader and the bindings available in a given module allows the easy use of different languages. Without this, it'd be more cumbersome to work with languages like Scribble or `at-exp`.

The second is that Racket provides overrideable context-sensitive macros such as `#%app`, `#%module-begin`, and so on that allow customization of, say, *every* function application within a module or of the entire module. This allows adding, for example, a type-checking pass over the entire module.

This isn't an exhaustive list of features that help build languages in Racket. If you're interested in reading more about it, the ["Languages as Libraries"](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/03/languages-as-libraries-pldi-2011.html) paper is worth reading.

Answer (score 15):

I'll recommend reading the paper ["Composable and Compilable Macros -
You Want it When?"](http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/macromod.pdf) by Matthew Flatt.

It explains how macros and modules work together in Racket.

Then implement a small language in Racket - say TinyBasic. 
Then compare with the other languages.

UPDATE

http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/jfp12-draft-fcdf.pdf

Answer (score 7):

See also [Matthew's reply](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2012-November/054731.html) for the same question after @Scott posted it on the list, with a more recent overview paper.